# llamar submit por js,jquery, ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

actualmente tengo este fragmento de script:

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $('body').on('click','a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $target = $(event.currentTarget);
        var destinationLocation = $target.attr('href');
        if (destinationLocation !== '#') {
            $('#objeto').load(
                destinationLocation
            );
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Y lo que hace es que cuando se de clic en un <  **a**  > busque el href y lo coloqué en un div llamado "objeto", bueno ahora lo que deseo es que támbien trabaje cuando le doy clic a un submit de un form, con estó llevar los datos capturados al php donde se le dará manejo.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $target.attr('submit');,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#objeto').html(data);
            }
        });
```

¿Puedo hacerlo?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pues el event submit no es de un botón es de un formulario asi que haces lo siguiente:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#frmEnvio').unbind().submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    Enviar(data);
  });
});

function Enviar(data){
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data;,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#objeto').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmEnvio">
  <input type="text" id="txtPalabra" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Enviame" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la ayuda, pregunta ... ¿Puedo trabajar, con dos form y que cada form tenga un id diferente que vaya a diferentes scripts? puesto que ya lo intente, pero siempre ejecuta el ultimo JavaScript